# Python - function is not returning variable (string)

Tags: python, return-value

I'm quite new to Python and this is for programming project in my CS course. The code seems to work perfectly EXCEPT on the last line of code:

```
 return finalWord
```

does not return anything. I have tried replacing this with:

```
 print(finalWord)
```

and it does print everything correctly.

Essentially in the program, I must create a Random class that pseudo-randomly generates numbers and then in the class Nonce, add several different words to the dictionary, and using the dictionary, create new, random words.

```
class Random:

    def __init__(self, seed):
        self.seed = seed

    def next(self, range):
        self.seed = (7 ** 5 * self.seed) % (2 ** 31 - 1)
        return self.seed % range

    def choose(self, objects):
        return objects[self.next(len(objects))]

class Nonce:

    def __init__(self, seed):
        self.first = []
        self.follow = {}
        self.random = Random(seed)

    def add(self, word):
        self.first += [word[0]]
        for x in range(0, len(word) - 1):
            self.follow.setdefault(word[x], []).append(word[x + 1])
        return None

    def make(self, size):
        nextLetter = self.random.choose(self.first)
        finalWord = nextLetter

        for x in range(1, size):
            if nextLetter in self.follow:
                followList = self.follow[nextLetter]
                nextLetter = self.random.choose(followList)
                finalWord += nextLetter
            else:
                finalWord += self.random.choose(self.first)

        return finalWord

potato = Nonce(101)
potato.add('python')
potato.add('java')
potato.add('html')
potato.make(5)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you calling the function and `print`-ing the result?

Comment: Maybe you could work [with your classmate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315643/python-attributeerror-instance-has-no-attribute)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling the function directly, then you must either do something with the returned value (like printing it) or store it in a variable for later use. The code is "not working" because you are never calling the function, at least not in the excerpt that you provided.

Printing the response:

```
print(instance_name.make())
```

Storing it in a variable:

```
variable_name = instance_name.make())
```

The code is where the instance of the class is called `instance_name`

In your code, you wrote `potato.make(5)`. The function runs, but does not print anything or store it in a variable. To print the response, you would need to do the following:

```
print(potato.make(5))
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I actually left that out. Yeah, I did call it. Let me modify that.

Comment: OH WOW, that is such an idiotic mistake. Thank you so much, lol.

Comment: @MichelleC. - If the problem was due to a simple oversight/typo, you can delete the question, as such questions aren't useful to future visitors.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It would be a duplicate rather than a typo